# Scala collect items of a type from a collection

Tags: scala, types, scala-collections

Consider an `Array[Any]`

```
val a = Array(1,2,"a")
a: Array[Any] = Array(1, 2, a)
```

We can collect all the items of type `Int` like this,

```
a.collect { case v: Int => v }
res: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)
```

Though how to define a function that collects items of a given type, having unsuccessfully tried this,

```
def co[T](a: Array[Any]) = a.collect { case v: T => v  }
warning: abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

which delivers

```
co[Int](a)
ArraySeq(1, 2, a)

co[String](a)
ArraySeq(1, 2, a)
```

Comment: Putting elements of different types such as integers and strings in one collection is not idiomatic in statically typed languages such as Scala.

Comment: @Jesper entirely agree, using scala.language.dynamics

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to provide a `ClassTag` for the pattern match to actually work:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def co[T: ClassTag](a: Array[Any]) = a.collect { case v: T => v  }
```